# Loop through javascript array and output the value if key is equal to or less than

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to automatically populate a unit price input with the values from a javascript array.

But for some reason I am getting the value `1` returned which is not in my array values, and the correct unit price is never outputted.

I've made a fiddle which might help debugging but it's a fairly basic the loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/up7avc1f/

Heres my script, I've commented what I am doing..

```
// the form
var $oForm = $('#custom_price_calculator');

// the price break array
var oPriceBreak = {
  100: 1.19,
  250: 1.17,
  500: 1.15,
  1000: 1.13,
  5000: 1.11,
  10000: 1.00,
};

// watch the quantity input for value changes
$('#inputCalculatorQty', $oForm).on('keyup', function () {

  // get our current value
  var iCurrentVal = $(this).val();

  console.log(iCurrentVal);

  // loop through my price break array
  $.each( oPriceBreak, function( qty, unit ) {

    // check if the current value is equal to or less than the qty key
    if( iCurrentVal <= qty ) {

        // if above returns true then set value as the unit price
        $('#inputCalculatorUnitPrice',$oForm).val(unit);

    }  

  });

});
```

I've added it as a snippet here too..

```js
// the form
var $oForm = $('#custom_price_calculator');

// the price break array
var oPriceBreak = {
  100: 1.19,
  250: 1.17,
  500: 1.15,
  1000: 1.13,
  5000: 1.11,
  10000: 1.00,
};

// watch the quantity input for value changes
$('#inputCalculatorQty', $oForm).on('keyup', function() {

  // get our current value
  var iCurrentVal = $(this).val();
  
  // loop through my price break array
  $.each(oPriceBreak, function(qty, unit) {

    // check if the current value is equal to or less than the qty key
    if (iCurrentVal <= qty) {

      // if above returns true then set value as the unit price
      $('#inputCalculatorUnitPrice', $oForm).val(unit);
      
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <form id="custom_price_calculator">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="1" min="1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" class="font-weight-bolder">Unit Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" min="0.01" value="1.19" required disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Origination</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="100" min="1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-4 mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sweets btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculate price</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to break out of the each loop when your condition is found.  I added a return false to your each loop.

```js
// the form
var $oForm = $('#custom_price_calculator');

// the price break array
var oPriceBreak = {
  100: 1.19,
  250: 1.17,
  500: 1.15,
  1000: 1.13,
  5000: 1.11,
  10000: 1.00,
};

// watch the quantity input for value changes
$('#inputCalculatorQty', $oForm).on('keyup', function() {

  // get our current value
  var iCurrentVal = $(this).val();
  
  // loop through my price break array
  $.each(oPriceBreak, function(qty, unit) {
    // check if the current value is equal to or less than the qty key
    if (parseInt(iCurrentVal) <= parseInt(qty)) {


      // if above returns true then set value as the unit price
      $('#inputCalculatorUnitPrice', $oForm).val(unit);
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <form id="custom_price_calculator">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="1" min="1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" class="font-weight-bolder">Unit Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" min="0.01" value="1.19" required disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
        <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Origination</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="100" min="1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-4 mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sweets btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculate price</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, makes total sense. Thats helped me alot, I just need to handle the last key now. Appreciate your input (no pun intended).

Comment: Your welcome and glad to help.  I forgot to mention that iCurrentVal and qty were strings, not integers, so I'm using parseInt to convert them to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the values in the `if()` as integers.

Checking the `typeof` `iCurrentVal` and `qty` will reveal that both values are strings.

Inside of:

```
if( iCurrentVal <= qty ) {...}
```

either do:

```
if(~~iCurrentVal <= ~~qty ) {...}
```

or use `parseInt()`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I was not breaking out my loop which fixed the issue how ever I am loving the `parseInt()` shortcode `~~`, I will use that in future.